# Correct syntax to compare values in JSTL <c:if test="${values.type}=='object'">

Tags: jsp, if-statement, jstl, el

I have an `if` statement that I am trying to perform with JSTL.

My code is below (the variables values is an ArrayList that contains a user defined object and type is a private property of that object, with public getter/setter methods):

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="values">
    <c:if test="${values.type}=='object'">
        <!-- code here -->
    </c:if>
</c:forEeach>
```

What would be the correct syntax of the part within the `test` attribute. The docs don't really help with that part http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The comparison needs to be evaluated fully inside EL `${ ... }`, not outside.

```
<c:if test="${values.type eq 'object'}">
```

As to the docs, those `${}` things are not JSTL, but EL (Expression Language) which is a whole subject at its own. JSTL (as every other JSP taglib) is just utilizing it. You can find some more EL examples [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaim).

```
<c:if test="#{bean.booleanValue}" />
<c:if test="#{bean.intValue gt 10}" />
<c:if test="#{bean.objectValue eq null}" />
<c:if test="#{bean.stringValue ne 'someValue'}" />
<c:if test="#{not empty bean.collectionValue}" />
<c:if test="#{not bean.booleanValue and bean.intValue ne 0}" />
<c:if test="#{bean.enumValue eq 'ONE' or bean.enumValue eq 'TWO'}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

---

By the way, unrelated to the concrete problem, if I guess your intent right, you could also just call [`Object#getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) and then [`Class#getSimpleName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName--) instead of adding a custom getter.

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="value">
    <c:if test="${value['class'].simpleName eq 'Object'}">
        <!-- code here -->
    </c:if>
</c:forEeach>
```

#### See also:

- [instanceof check in EL expression language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314214/instanceof-check-in-el-expression-language/)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it. It doesn't seem to resolve to false when I need it to. That's probably my mistake somewhere, if I figure it out and it's relevant, I'll post the solution here when I find it.

Comment: The `getType()` must return a `String` to get it to work. Plus, it's case sensitive. That's why I used `Object` (with uppercase) in my 2nd example. Print `${values.type}` plain to be sure.

Comment: I am looking over everything twice, thrice etc. and everything looks fine. The problem is not getting the value ... I have checked that, this part is working, the problem is that the condition is not resolving to false if the type=='number' ... I'll keep looking for clues.

Comment: Thanks, all is solved :) was a long process, none of which is really relevant to the question, just common sense, so I won't explain.