# How to pass class as method parameter with EL

Tags: jsf, el

Hi i'm new to jsf/el and i'm looking for a solution to pass a class ex : "Student.class" as a method parameter to my method defined in my backing bean. By the way i tested the same overloaded method using a string parameter without any issues but i prefer a Class parameter over a String parameter for my use case.

MyBean.java:

```
public void createPersonType(Class className) {
    // Person factory code goes here
}
```

person.xhtml:

```
<... actionListener="#{myBean.createPersonType(Student.class)}" />
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think EL allows that. Why not create overloaded methods like `createStudent()`.  Your MenuItem is already specific why not have it call a specific method.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported in EL.

Just use an `enum` instead if you want to enforce type safety.

```java
public interface Person {

    public enum Type {
        STUDENT, TEACHER, ETC;
    }

    public Type getType();
}
```

```java
public void createPersonType(Person.Type personType) {
    // Person factory code goes here
}
```

```xml
<... actionListener="#{myBean.createPersonType('STUDENT')}" />
```

JSF will automatically convert the string to actual enum.

Instead of the string, you can also use `<f:importConstants>` (or `<o:importConstants>`).

```xml
<f:metadata>
    <f:importConstants type="com.example.Person.Type" var="PersonType" />
</f:metadata>
...
<... actionListener="#{myBean.createPersonType(PersonType.STUDENT)}" />
```

#### See also:

- [How to reference constants in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/how-to-reference-constants-in-el/)
- [instanceof check in EL expression language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314214/instanceof-check-in-el-expression-language)

Answer (score -1):

You could pass the whole class reference `your.package.Student` as a `String`. Your method would look like this:

```
public void createPersonType(String className) {
    Class<?> class = Class.forName(className);
}
```

Comment: From the question: *"By the way i tested the same overloaded method using a string parameter without any issues but i prefer a Class parameter over a String parameter for my use case."*.

Comment: Oh my bad, I somehow missed that part.